# List of dependent objects (from different schemas) for a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Problem:** get a list of dependent objects from schemas A and B for a view V that is stored in the B schema.

**What I know for sure is:** View V pulls data from the materialized view MV in schema B and
MV pulls data from a view V2, which resides in schema A.

**Ideally** I would get a list like the following one: B.V -> B.MV -> A.V2

**What I have tried doing so far**:

1. `select * from all_dependencies where name = 'V';` - this only gave
   me the information that V pools data from MV - id didn't go deeper
   than that

   1.1 I've tried doing `select * from ALL_MVIEW_DETAIL_RELATIONS where MVIEW_NAME = 'MV'` - using the MV name from the first query, but for some reason this particular MV is not in the  ALL_MVIEW_DETAIL_RELATIONS table (my colleague suggests it is because of the complexity of the underlying view V2)

2.I tried suggesting that I know the name of the very bottom view V2 and went up the hierarchy using this query `select * from all_dependencies where referenced_name = 'V2'` - it didn't help either

Please take your time to read through this and do let me know how to solve this, as I am start getting a bit desperate ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have materialized views at the moment, but here is my understanding:

This should give you B.MV

```
--query 1
select referenced_owner, referenced_name 
from all_dependencies where name = 'V'
```

This should give you A.V2

```
--query 2
select detailobj_owner, detailobj_name 
from all_mview_detail_relations where 
(owner, mview_name) in 
(
--query 1
select referenced_owner, referenced_name 
from all_dependencies where name = 'V'
)
```

And this should give you all the tables/view that are used to build A.V2

```
select referenced_owner, referenced_name 
from all_dependencies where  
(owner, name) in 
(
--query 2
select detailobj_owner, detailobj_name 
from all_mview_detail_relations where 
(owner, mview_name) in 
(
--query 1
select referenced_owner, referenced_name 
from all_dependencies where name = 'V'
)
)
```

Is it working? Or maybe just some food for thought...

Comment: That's a great answer, but :) for some reason your query 2 would not return any results in my particular case because the B.MV is not displayed in all_mvie_detail_relations. I haven't found an answer to the "why?" for now ;)

Comment: you can try to use all_dependencies instead.

Comment: In all_dependencies B.MV references itself. It's a dead end :)

Comment: another idea, MV is a table that is based on view, right? Maybe you would need one more step like what is a view that this MV is based on. Then for that view, you probably will be able to see dependencies. I may be wrong - no appliance to test the idea.

Comment: MV is a view that is based on the table, which bears the same name. Still nothing I figured out about all this issue. What bugs me is that my colleague had managed to see those relations somehow but he can't remember how he did that -_-